# How to add image in table row programmatically?

Tags: android, image, tablelayout

I am developing an android app. I need to populate my list with images. I want to insert image in table layout row by row using array. Can you guide me how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code and make changes according to your code

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(mContext);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int j = 0; j < mCols; j++) {

            ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on)
            tr.addView(view);
        }
        table.addView(tr);
    }
```

Comment: @Brent Turner how to change the image particular position